# The error during executing selenium webdriver operations either in Jupyter or in Colab

Tags: parsing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to execute the following code, in Jupyter and Colab:

```
import time
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver

#driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Desktop/chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32')

driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

And getting the error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (4.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3[socks]<3,>=1.26 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from selenium) (1.26.15)
Requirement already satisfied: trio~=0.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from selenium) (0.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: trio-websocket~=0.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from selenium) (0.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2021.10.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from selenium) (2022.12.7)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (23.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sortedcontainers in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: async-generator>=1.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: idna in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: outcome in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: exceptiongroup>=1.0.0rc9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wsproto>=0.14 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from trio-websocket~=0.9->selenium) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PySocks!=1.5.7,<2.0,>=1.5.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from urllib3[socks]<3,>=1.26->selenium) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h11<1,>=0.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from wsproto>=0.14->trio-websocket~=0.9->selenium) (0.14.0)
<ipython-input-3-13003c8c2f4f>:8: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-13003c8c2f4f> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 # driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/YOUR_USERNAME/Desktop/chromedriver')
      7 
----> 8 driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32')
      9 
     10 driver.get('http://www.google.com/');

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    243                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    244             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 245         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Stacktrace:
#0 0x558c642e34e3 <unknown>
#1 0x558c64012c76 <unknown>
#2 0x558c64039757 <unknown>
#3 0x558c64038029 <unknown>
#4 0x558c64076ccc <unknown>
#5 0x558c6407647f <unknown>
#6 0x558c6406dde3 <unknown>
#7 0x558c640432dd <unknown>
#8 0x558c6404434e <unknown>
#9 0x558c642a33e4 <unknown>
#10 0x558c642a73d7 <unknown>
#11 0x558c642b1b20 <unknown>
#12 0x558c642a8023 <unknown>
#13 0x558c642761aa <unknown>
#14 0x558c642cc6b8 <unknown>
#15 0x558c642cc847 <unknown>
#16 0x558c642dc243 <unknown>
#17 0x7fba2327e609 start_thread
```

Where is my mistake?

I tried all possible resources in internet and stackoverflow.

Packages for chrome, selenium and webdriver correspond to each other.

When I ran downloaded chromedriver.exe
(do not know why zip is named as 'chromedriver_win32', not win64. Though I see another files: 'geckodriver-v0.33.0-win32.zip' and 'geckodriver-v0.33.0-win-aarch64.zip')
it started, showed the messages:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

and hanging.

So, I waited for half an hour, then stopped this. Then, thinking that it should work during the code execution tried the code again.

The message "**Only local connections are allowed**" must be a key, but the proposed soluions I found didn't work for me.
It seems that here should be the strong sequence of settings actions. Probably I did something wrong. Or it's a wrong zip for chromedriver? Or it should be the default path for the driver, on C? I'm stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've got the answer to my own question (many approaches and sudden findings in this very forum helped):

in the code row with

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32')
```

must be not simply a path (directory) but a fully specified file location, with the extention, i. e.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\Anaconda\etc\chromedriver.exe')
```